# What is the basic relationship between the amount of thermal radiation absorbed and emitted, and the surface temperature?

Tags: classical-mechanics, thermal-radiation

What is the basic relationship between the emission/absorption of thermal radiation and the surface temp.?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. This is probably too broad for us to answer; you might think of editing it to reduce its scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual relationship is the [Stefan-Boltzmann law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law).  It only really applies to blackbodies, but it's a pretty good approximation for most bodies.  If a body is in equilibrium (so its temperature isn't changing), the absorbed power is equal to the emitted power.  Do you have a more specific question?